# when i write note for each row is write note for every row. HOw i can write note for each row of table

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<!---Show information -->
<!--table-->
<section class=" container mx-auto p-6 font-mono">
    <div class="w-full mb-8 overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
        <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto table">
            <table id="myTable" class=" w-full content-table">
                <thead class="bg-stone-500">
                    <tr class="mytable text-xs font-semibold  text-left text-white " data-user-cards-container>

                        <th class="px-4  py-3">Name</th>
                        <th class="px-4 border-l-2 py-3">Entries Date</th>
                        <th class="px-4 border-l-2 py-3">Phone</th>
                        <th class="px-4  border-l-2 py-3">Email</th>
                        <th class="px-4  border-l-2 py-3">Form Name</th>
                        <th class="px-4  border-l-2 py-3"></th>




                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="data" class="text-xs text-stone-400">




                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div
                class="px-5 py-5 bg-white border-t flex flex-col xs:flex-row items-center xs:justify-between          ">
                <div class="inline-flex mt-2 xs:mt-0">
                    <button id="prevButton"
                        class="text-sm bg-stone-300 hover:bg-gray-400 hover:border-gray-200 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded-l">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-chevrons-left"></i>
                        Prev
                    </button>
                    <button id="nextButton"
                        class="text-sm bg-stone-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded-r">
                        Next
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-chevrons-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

//Json Javascript notation\
    let clientData = []
    let pageSize = 10;


    let currentPage = 1
    async function renderTable(page = 1) {
        await getData()
        if (page == 1) {
            prevButton.style.visibility = "hidden"
        } else {
            prevButton.style.visibility = "visible"

        }
        if (page == numberOfPages()) {
            nextButton.style.visibility = "hidden"
        } else {
            nextButton.style.visibility = "visible"
        }
        let temp = ""

        ///create HTMl table 




        clientData.filter((row, index) => {
            let start = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize
            let end = currentPage * pageSize

            if (index >= start && index  {
            temp += ""
            temp += `${item.Name}`
            temp += `${item.Date.slice(0, 10)}`
            temp += `${item.Email}`
            temp += `${item.Phone}`
            temp += `${item.FormTitle}`
            temp += ` Note
                             `
            ""
        })
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp


    }
    renderTable()

    //pagination



    function previosPage() {
        if (currentPage > 1)
            currentPage--;
        renderTable(currentPage)
    }
    function nextPage() {
        if ((currentPage * pageSize)

Comment: Use "code sample" to share your code please ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.